# Access: a Form with 2 subforms (Same table)

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a Form of Payments, and I want to split the actives and pasives with two subforms.

I have made it, and works! The table **Payments** store the values.
The actives and pasives are in a table.

ID -> Number

Description -> String

Pasive -> True/false

I have created two Forms, for actives and pasives. Each form displays the corresponding values.
Also I have created main Form that contains two subforms (actives and pasives)

When I insert a Payment 
[image]

GREAT! It works!
[image]

But, when I open again the form, the values are disordered.

[image]

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it understand you correctly. It looks like your subforms don't know which data is passive and which is active. Try this:

1. Instead of yes/no field in your table, you could rather create field with dropdown list that allows you to pick one of two values: *passive* or *active*. Let's name that field: *transactionType*.
2. Then you should add *transactionType* control to each subform.
3. In the first subform you set default value for *transactionType* control as a `="active"`, in the second subform: `="passive"`.
4. Now you can set visible parameter of *transactionType* controls in both subforms to *no*. In form view you won't see them, but if you create new record, the will add proper information to your table.
5. Are your subforms based on query? If no, go to subforms data source, create query based on your table and in the criteria of *transactionType* field set respectively `"active"` (in the firs subform) and `"passive"` (in the second one).

When you reopen
    your form, thanks to query filter you have set in step 5, subforms will
    display only actives or only passives. If you chose that solution, this will work for new data only. If you already have some data in your table, you should manually complete *trasactionType* for each existing record.